# Sorting folder size not working - RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, redhat

I am using du -h --max-depth=2 to get list of folders by size upto 2 levels down. Problem is I am not able to sort them in max folder size.

Normally this can be achieved by using du -k | sort -nr * but I can't use it here since it conflicts (the -s argument) with the --max-depth=2 argument.

Can someone please suggest if there is any other way to achieve this. I need to keep the list in human readable format though.

```
478M  var
500K  usr/sdfijf/best
568K  user/dbuser
56M  etc/basic/linux
68K  var/redhat
9.0K  user/aunix
```

I have following two columns and was expecting to sort them by the human readable folder size with biggest folders being on top (so descending and reverse order basically)

Thanks,
Morgan

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-h` flag to `sort`:

```
-h, --human-numeric-sort
       compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
```

So `du -h --max-depth=2 | sort -hr`.

Comment: No Carlpett, when I did it, it gave me an error saying "sort: invalid option -- h, Try `sort --help' for more information." I think problem is we can't use --max-depth and other arguments like -h at the same time. But thanks for your help anyway.!!

Comment: @user94072: No, the error is reported from `sort`, so your version of `sort` probably does not have the `-h` flag. You could try replacing the `-h` in `sort -h -r` with either `--sort=human-numeric` or `--human-numeric-sort` to see if those are supported ways of expressing it instead.

Comment: Also, could you post the output of `sort --version`?

Comment: Hi Carl, its - 
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.97
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @user: Ok, the human readable format got incorporated in version 7.5 apparantly (which was released in the end of 2009). If you cannot upgrade for some reason, then you'll have to resort to some workaround, such as the one suggested by anon

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways could be `du -k --max-depth=2 | sort -nr |awk '{ print $2}'|xargs du -sh` but not sure if it is efficient

Comment: Glad to help! But as carlpett mentioned this is a workaround. The solution provided by carlpett is definitely better; this workaround is much much slower as it involves repeated du operations